# ABCPDF with Gecko rendering does not render the same in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf, gecko, abcpdf

Right now I'm using the latest ABC PDF version, and use the Gecko rendering engine. However, I notice that there are small differences between the way Firefox renders the HTML I'm adding to my PDF, and the way ABC PDF interprets the HTML. I was wondering if there is anything that can be done against this?

I'm asking about Firefox specifically because I thought that browser used the same Gecko rendering engine as ABCPDF did, so I thought it would be 100% the same.

Does anyone know about this? Couldn't find much about this on the internet, though I do admit that I find it hard to come up with the correct search terms.

Answer (score 4):

By default ABCpdf will use the 'print' css media type whereas Firefox will be using 'screen', this can be changed by setting the [media property](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/media.htm).

```
var doc = new Doc()
doc.HtmlOptions.Media = MediaType.Screen
```

If the differences are more subtle it may be worth taking a look at [engine configuration](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm).

It is important to note the Gecko engine used in ABCpdf is independent from the engine used in any local Firefox installation, it should be assumed that it will be different in both version and configuration.